# ArrayList is throwing IndexOutOfBoundsException despite it being initialized in function and being populated using add function

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, retrofit2

I am retrieving data from a json weblink using retrofit2 which is working as intended and I checked the debugger and it shows that the elements are being added in the private variables, however, I am attempting to display the String elements that I obtained from the json link and added to an ArrayList and when I call the RecyclerViewAdapter to display the results I keep getting an IndexOutOfBoundsException saying that the elements are in fact null?
In the FetchContent object init block I am calling getRetroFitData() to connect to the json URL and retrieve the data in the json link and then save the results in the private variables in that same function. After that when I call the recycler view I add the results to the data class by using the getter functions to create each Item in the jsonITEMS variable but during this process I get the exception thrown.

I cannot figure out why or how the ArrayList becomes null after I iterate them:

**ItemFragment.kt**

```
package com.example.fetch_coding_exercise

import android.os.Bundle
import android.util.Log
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.GridLayoutManager
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import retrofit2.Call
import retrofit2.Callback
import retrofit2.Response
import retrofit2.Retrofit
import retrofit2.converter.gson.GsonConverterFactory

/**
 * A fragment representing a list of Items.
 */
const val PRIMARY_URL = "" // Intentionally left empty do to contents of link

class ItemFragment : Fragment() {

private var columnCount = 1

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

    arguments?.let {
        columnCount = it.getInt(ARG_COLUMN_COUNT)
    }
}

override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View? {
    val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_item_list, container, false)

    // Set the adapter
    if (view is RecyclerView) {
        with(view) {
            layoutManager = when {
                columnCount <= 1 -> LinearLayoutManager(context)
                else -> GridLayoutManager(context, columnCount)
            }
            adapter = MyItemRecyclerViewAdapter(FetchContent.jsonITEMS)
        }
    }
    return view
}

override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
}

companion object {

    // TODO: Customize parameter argument names
    const val ARG_COLUMN_COUNT = "column-count"

    // TODO: Customize parameter initialization
    @JvmStatic
    fun newInstance(columnCount: Int) =
        ItemFragment().apply {
            arguments = Bundle().apply {
                putInt(ARG_COLUMN_COUNT, columnCount)
            }
        }
}
}
```

**MyItemRecyclerViewAdapter.kt**

```
package com.example.fetch_coding_exercise

import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.widget.TextView
import android.widget.Toast

import com.example.fetch_coding_exercise.placeholder.PlaceholderContent.PlaceholderItem
import com.example.fetch_coding_exercise.databinding.FragmentItemBinding
import retrofit2.Call
import retrofit2.Callback
import retrofit2.Response
import retrofit2.Retrofit
import retrofit2.converter.gson.GsonConverterFactory

/**
 * [RecyclerView.Adapter] that can display a [PlaceholderItem].
 * TODO: Replace the implementation with code for your data type.
 */
class MyItemRecyclerViewAdapter(private val values: List<FetchContent.FetchDataItem>)
    : RecyclerView.Adapter<MyItemRecyclerViewAdapter.ViewHolder>() {

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {

        return ViewHolder(
            FragmentItemBinding.inflate(
                LayoutInflater.from(parent.context),
                parent,
                false
            )
        )
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val item = values[position]
        holder.userIdView.text = item.id
        holder.listIdView.text = item.listId
        holder.nameView.text = item.name
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int = values.size

    inner class ViewHolder(binding: FragmentItemBinding) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root) {
        val userIdView: TextView = binding.userID
        val listIdView: TextView = binding.listID
        val nameView: TextView = binding.name

        override fun toString(): String {
            return super.toString() + " '" + nameView.text + "'"
        }
    }

}
```

**FetchContent.kt**

```
package com.example.fetch_coding_exercise

import java.util.ArrayList
import java.util.HashMap

object FetchContent {

    val jsonITEMS: MutableList<FetchDataItem> = ArrayList()

    private val COUNT = 25


    init {
        fetchedData().getRetroFitData()
        for (i in 0..COUNT) {
            addItem(createFetchItem(i))
        }
    }



    private fun addItem(item: FetchDataItem) {
        jsonITEMS.add(item)
    }

    private fun createFetchItem(position: Int): FetchDataItem {
        return FetchDataItem(
            fetchedData().getID(position), fetchedData().getListID(position), fetchedData().getName(position))
    }

    data class FetchDataItem(val id: String, val listId: String, val name: String) {
        override fun toString(): String = listId
    }
}
```

**fetchedData.kt**

```
package com.example.fetch_coding_exercise

import android.util.Log
import retrofit2.Call
import retrofit2.Callback
import retrofit2.Response
import retrofit2.Retrofit
import retrofit2.converter.gson.GsonConverterFactory
import java.util.jar.Attributes

class fetchedData : ArrayList<fetchedDataItem>() {

    private val retroId = arrayListOf<String>()
    private val retroListId = arrayListOf<String>()
    private val retroName = arrayListOf<String>()
    private var retroCOUNT = 0

    fun getRetroFitData() {
        val retrofitBuilder = Retrofit.Builder()
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .baseUrl(PRIMARY_URL)
            .build()
            .create(interfaceAPI::class.java)

        val retrofitData = retrofitBuilder.getData()

        retrofitData.enqueue(object : Callback<List<FetchContent.FetchDataItem>?> {
            override fun onResponse(
                call: Call<List<FetchContent.FetchDataItem>?>,
                response: Response<List<FetchContent.FetchDataItem>?>
            ) {
                val responseBody = response.body()!!
                retroCOUNT = responseBody.size

                for (i in responseBody.indices) {
                    if (!responseBody[i].name.isNullOrEmpty()) {
                        retroId.add(responseBody[i].id)
                        retroListId.add(responseBody[i].listId)
                        retroName.add(responseBody[i].name)
                    } else {
                        retroCOUNT--
                    }
                }

                println("retroId: " + retroId)
                println("retroListId: " + retroListId)
                println("retroName: " + retroName)
            }

            override fun onFailure(call: Call<List<FetchContent.FetchDataItem>?>, t: Throwable) {
                Log.d("FetchContent", "onFailure:"+t.message)
            }
        })
    }

    fun getID(index: Int): String {
        return if (retroId[index].isEmpty())
            "null"
        else
            retroId[index]
    }

    fun getListID(index: Int): String {
        return retroListId[index]
    }

    fun getName(index: Int): String {
        return retroName[index]
    }


}
```

**Logcat Error Message**

```
2021-09-30 14:26:54.022 28416-28416/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.fetch_coding_exercise, PID: 28416
    java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
        at com.example.fetch_coding_exercise.ItemFragment.onCreateView(ItemFragment.kt:48)
        at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2963)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.createView(FragmentStateManager.java:518)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.moveToExpectedState(FragmentStateManager.java:282)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStore.moveToExpectedState(FragmentStore.java:112)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1647)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.dispatchStateChange(FragmentManager.java:3128)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.dispatchActivityCreated(FragmentManager.java:3072)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentController.dispatchActivityCreated(FragmentController.java:251)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.onStart(FragmentActivity.java:502)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.onStart(AppCompatActivity.java:246)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1435)
        at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:8018)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleStartActivity(ActivityThread.java:3475)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.performLifecycleSequence(TransactionExecutor.java:221)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.cycleToPath(TransactionExecutor.java:201)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeLifecycleState(TransactionExecutor.java:173)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:97)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2066)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
     Caused by: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0
        at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:437)
        at com.example.fetch_coding_exercise.fetchedData.getID(fetchedData.kt:57)
        at com.example.fetch_coding_exercise.FetchContent.createFetchItem(FetchContent.kt:48)
        at com.example.fetch_coding_exercise.FetchContent.<clinit>(FetchContent.kt:33)
```

Comment: i don't know what `fetchedData().getRetroFitData()` does,  but are you sure this completes and gets all your data by the time the rest of your code is executing ? it probably isn't synchronous

Comment: Sorry I forgot to include that class as well. I added it to my question now. 
Also how could it not be synchronous?

Comment: `how could it not be synchronous?` because api calls aren't

Comment: That honestly may be the issue then, seems the most probable in my case.

Comment: the API call is indeed asynchronous because that's how `enqueue` works (see the [documentation](https://square.github.io/retrofit/2.x/retrofit/retrofit2/Call.html#enqueue-retrofit2.Callback-)). It's only within the `onResponse` callback that you can actually see the response (assuming the call has not failed)